# asyncio.create_task() not running function in background in Python 3.11.3

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, python-3.11

I've created a Python 3.11.3 program that uses asyncio to run an async function in the background. I've tried using `asyncio.create_task()` to run the function in the background, but the program keeps waiting for the function to finish before continuing execution.

Here's my code:

```py
import asyncio
from time import sleep

import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()


async def infinite_async_func():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("infinite_async_func is running")


async def main():
    print("Main is running")
    asyncio.create_task(infinite_async_func())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
    print("done")
```

I've also tried adding the `async with` syntax for async context managers introduced in Python 3.11, but I'm not sure if it's relevant to my problem.

What could be causing my program to wait for the function to finish? How can I run the async function in the background correctly using asyncio in Python 3.11.3?

Thank you in advance for your help.

From the output I expect something like this:

```
Main is running
infinite_async_func is running
done
infinite_async_func is running
...
```

Comment: The main coroutine will be blocked until the called coroutine is complete. So in your case, main function is waiting for infinite_async_func

Comment: @Tatarinho you're right, maybe this is not the right example of what I'm trying to achieve. In my case I just need to run `infinite_async_func` without await it and continue with the execution of the code

Comment: I have same issue, i use async with semaphore
and asyncio.create_task awaits until my method goes completed

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comment, in your code main coroutine is wating for infinite_async_func coro. Also IF it would be possible like you wrote it, print('done') is last command of your code, you can't expect that main Python process will be working and collecting data from some background coroutine.

I think that the closest will be something like below:

```
import asyncio


async def infinite_async_func():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("infinite_async_func is running")


async def main():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Main is running")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    asyncio.ensure_future(infinite_async_func())
    loop.run_forever()
    print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Tatarinho said: asyncio will wait for all coroutines in the event loop to finish before moving on in the code. If one task in the event loop is giving up control, the event loop will move on to another task in the event loop. However it will not move on to something outside of the event loop.

The print statement you have is outside of the event loop so it will not execute until your infite function finishes. But everything inside your main() function will execute since it is part of the coroutine:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep

import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()


async def infinite_async_func():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("infinite_async_func is running")


async def main():
    print("Main is running")
    await infinite_async_func()
    print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
    print("won't be executed")
```

This will print

```
Main is running
infinite_async_func is running
done
infinite_async_func is running
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) says that the loop will run until stop() is called. That means that the code after run_forever() will not be executed until the loop is stopped.

If you want to have something like the behavior you're expecting you can create a second asynchronous task, something like :

```
async def print_after_delay(delay):
    print("print_after_delay is running")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print("print_after_delay is done")


async def main():
    print("Main is running")
    asyncio.create_task(infinite_async_func())
    asyncio.create_task(print_after_delay(5))
```

This will produce an output looking like that :

```
Main is running
print_after_delay is running
infinite_async_func is running
. . .
infinite_async_func is running
print_after_delay is done
infinite_async_func is running
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, your second task, which you want to execute while your first task is running must also be part of the event loop or Task Group. Here is one way using the style of the examples from the python asyncio documentation.

```
async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def say_infinite_after(delay, what):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_infinite_after(2, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

# Wait until both tasks are completed
await task1
await task2

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output will be

```
hello
world
hello
hello
hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this does not solve my problem because it waits for an infinite loop.